# I need to inject a Tealium code in below attached comment.js file

Tags: javascript

Following code needs to be inserted  in the comment.js file

```
(function(a,b,c,d){
        a='//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/sapient/main/qa/utag.js';
        b=document;c='script';d=b.createElement(c);d.src=a;d.type='text/java'+c;d.async=true;
        a=b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(d,a);
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

following below is the comment.js file code

```
(function() {

/**
 * "Slides" the comment form in and out of view
 * 
 * @method toggleCommentForm
 * @param {Event} e Event object
 */
function toggleCommentForm(e) {
    var activityItem = AJS.$(e.target).closest('div.activity-item'),
        form = activityItem.find('form.activity-item-comment-form');

    e.preventDefault();

    if (!form.length) {
        form = buildCommentForm(e, activityItem);
        form.appendTo(activityItem);
    }
    if (form.is(':visible')) {
        form.slideUp(function() {
            form.trigger('contentResize.streams').removeClass('ready');
        });
    } else {
        form.slideDown(function() {
            form.find('textarea').focus();
            // remove 'display: block' set by slideDown fn so that we can hide the form with css
            form.css({display: ''});
            form.trigger('contentResize.streams').addClass('ready');
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Returns html for the inline add comment form
 * 
 * @method buildCommentForm
 * @param {Event} e Event object
 * @param {Object} activityItem the .activity-item div
 * @return {HTMLElement}
 */
function buildCommentForm(e, activityItem) {
    var form,
        fieldset,
        submit,
        feedItem;

    if (!e.data || !e.data.feedItem) {
        ActivityStreams.InlineActions.statusMessage(activityItem, AJS.I18n.getText('streams.comment.action.error.invalid.comment'), 'error');
        return null;
    }

    feedItem = e.data.feedItem;
    form = AJS.$('<form class="activity-item-comment-form" method="post" action=""></form>').css({display: 'none'});

    fieldset = AJS.$('<fieldset></fieldset>')
        .appendTo(form);
    AJS.$('<input type="hidden" name="replyTo">')
        .val(feedItem.links['http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/reply-to'])
        .appendTo(fieldset);

    // The name of this hidden XSRF token field must correspond with the value of CROSS_PRODUCT_TOKEN_PARAM
    // in the com.atlassian.streams.internal.servlet.XsrfAwareRequest class (in the Streams Aggregator plugin)
    AJS.$('<input type="hidden" name="xsrfToken">')
            .val(window.top.AJS.$("#atlassian-token").attr("content"))
            .appendTo(fieldset);

    AJS.$('<textarea cols="40" rows="6" name="comment"></textarea>')
        .appendTo(fieldset);

    submit = AJS.$('<div class="submit"></div>')
        .appendTo(form);
    AJS.$('<button name="submit" type="submit"></button>')
        .text(AJS.I18n.getText('streams.comment.action.add'))
        .appendTo(submit);
    AJS.$('<a href="#" class="streams-cancel"></a>')
        .text(AJS.I18n.getText('streams.comment.action.cancel'))
        .click(toggleCommentForm)
        .appendTo(submit);

    form.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = AJS.$(e.target),
            commentBody = AJS.$.trim(form.find("textarea").val());
        if (commentBody.length === 0) {
            ActivityStreams.InlineActions.statusMessage(activityItem, AJS.I18n.getText('streams.comment.action.error.add.comment'), 'error');
            return;
        }
        form.find("button").attr("disabled", "true");

        AJS.$.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : ActivityStreams.getBaseUrl() + '/plugins/servlet/streamscomments',
            data : form.serialize(),
            dataType : 'json',
            global: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                form.trigger('beginInlineAction');
            },
            complete: function() {
                form.trigger('completeInlineAction');
            },
            success : function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                toggleCommentForm(e);
                form.find("button").removeAttr("disabled");
                form.find("textarea").val("");

                //302 is not considered an error, but JIRA is using it to return blocked url errors https://sdog.jira.com/browse/JSTDEV-670 and https://studio.atlassian.com/browse/STRM-1982
                if(xhr.status == 302) {
                    ActivityStreams.InlineActions.statusMessage(activityItem, AJS.I18n.getText('streams.comment.action.error.invalid.comment'), 'error');
                }
                else {
                    ActivityStreams.InlineActions.statusMessage(activityItem, AJS.I18n.getText('streams.comment.action.success.add.comment'), 'info');
                    form.trigger('issueCommented', feedItem);
                }
            },
            error : function(response) {
                var data = (response && response.data) || response,
                    subcode = (data && data.responseText && AJS.json.parse(data.responseText).subCode) || 'streams.comment.action.error.invalid.comment';
                toggleCommentForm(e);
                form.find('button').removeAttr('disabled');
                ActivityStreams.InlineActions.statusMessage(activityItem, AJS.I18n.getText(subcode), 'error');
            }
        });
    });

    return form;
}

/**
 * Builds an anchor element that toggles the comment form if feedItem has a replyTo link
 * 
 * @method buildTrigger
 * @param {String} label The display text for the link
 * @param {Object} feedItem Object representing the activity item
 * @return {HTMLElement}
 */
function buildTrigger(label, feedItem) {
    //if no reply to link exists in the feed item, do not bind the entry to a comment handler
    if (!feedItem.links['http://streams.atlassian.com/syndication/reply-to']) {
        return null;
    } 

    return AJS.$('<a href="#" class="activity-item-comment-link"></a>')
        .text(label)
        .bind('click', {feedItem: feedItem}, toggleCommentForm);
}

/**
 * Builds a "Comment" link that toggles the comment form
 *
 * @method buildCommentLink
 * @param {Object} feedItem Object representing the activity item
 * @return {HTMLElement}
 */
function buildCommentLink(feedItem) {
    var label = AJS.I18n.getText('streams.comment.action.comment');
    if (feedItem.application !== 'com.atlassian.jira' && feedItem.type === 'comment') {
        label = AJS.I18n.getText('streams.comment.action.reply');
    }
    return buildTrigger(label, feedItem);
}

// Registers the comment action for various types in the feed
ActivityStreams.registerAction('article comment page issue file job', buildCommentLink, 1);
```

})();